# Literature for geometry

Tags: geometry

I know that this platform is for people with more advanced questions, nevertheless, I hope you can help me. I actually aquired a quite strong knowledge in Calculus, Algebra, Topology, ... but just recognized (during reading some of Newton‘s paper‘s, that I don‘t really know a lot about geometry.
Can you give me some books of ressources with which I can dive into this topic?
Thanks for every answer!

Comment: Any interesting question is a charity for the mind 

Comment: What do you mean by geometry? There's differential geometry, algebraic geometry, euclidean geometry, non-Euclidean geometry, etc.

Comment: As I said, introductory geometry as e.g.  Newton used

Comment: Have you read books on classical geometry written by the ancient masters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have said, I'm guessing that you are referring to Euclidean geometry. The most rigorous recent treatment that I have read of this subject is [Axiomatic Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821884786) by Lee. It covers basic results from first principles with largely classical methods, though there is plenty of more advanced results in Euclidean geometry that are not covered in it. For many further interesting ideas, see [Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883858398) by Chen. It's more focused on olympiad problem-solving and covering ground on techniques than on bolting down every detail of a rigorous argument, but as Darij Grinberg says in this [cut-the-knot page](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/InscriptibleQuadrilateral.shtml),

> What can indeed be said to its disadvantage is that it is incomplete in the very way it is written - but this is the case for many geometric proofs, alas...

So it is not uncommon for geometers to subtract absolute rigor in favor of saving space and allowing humans to understand the main points of an argument. I say this so that you can both appreciate the rigor of Lee's book and enjoy the array of methods that are summarized in Chen's book.

As Darij Grinberg says in his [recommendations list](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/about.html#books), Coxeter's [Geometry Revisited](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883856190) is a good one too. It's old but has a nice mix of ideas in a small amount of space. As a review says, "The book is rich in remarkable facts..."

The United Kingdom Mathematics Trust has some decent books too on the subject, such as [Plane Euclidean Geometry](https://www.ukmt.org.uk/product/87) and [The Geometry of the Triangle](https://www.ukmt.org.uk/product/88).

For books of an olympiad flavor, check out Titu Andreescu's [XYZ Press bookstore](https://www.awesomemath.org/shop/), especially [Lemmas In Olympiad Geometry](https://www.awesomemath.org/product/lemmas-in-olympiad-geometry/).

Good luck. I do wonder though if Euclidean geometry is worth learning in the present day, outside of mathematical competitions or historical interest, given its lack of relevance within modern mathematics and the existence of areas in mathematics that are far more applicable outside of mathematics.

Comment: Also, while revisiting Euclidean geometry after my university education in mathematics, I found that much of my knowledge of geometry was based on intuition or assumptions. To make sense of matters, I inevitably had to use topology, like the Jordan curve theorem, or analytic methods like complex numbers or coordinates.